# How to remove android dependencies from cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, dependencies

I'm using cordova in one project with 15+ plugins. After updating to the latest cordova cli + cordova android library, a couple of plugins started to fail. I identified the issue has to do with the android dependencies added by each plugin. On the files project.properties and build.gradle in app folder I noticed duplicated entries for 'com.android.support:support-v4:27'. After I edited manualy build.gradle to add only one 'com.android.support:support-v4' matching my sdk, it worked.

** My platforms & plugins folders are not checked in my github. They are generated automatically, so I don't have the option to edit them directly.

**
Using cordova 8.1.2 and cordova-android 7.1.4

Q1: How can I make sure my android cordova project has unique compat libraries?

Q2: How can I overwrite or remove jar libraries from the project generated by cordova?

Thanks

Comment: I know this is not the answer that you are looking for but I had to downgrade to Cordova 7.1 for everything to work properly. Cordova 8.x breaks too many plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The following plugin did what I needed fixing the issue. Basically I had a conflict of android support libraries with mismatching versions. The plugin resolves the conflicts fixing all android dependencies with the one I specified.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release